# Will binary heap run faster if preallocated to fixed length?

Tags: python, memory-management, heap-memory, a-star

I want to solve a really big maze with python. I use A* algorithm and binary heap as a priority queue... But it is too slow...
Will it run faster if I preallocated heap to a fixed size e.g. count all places in maze and use list of this length as a heap?

Thank you!

Comment: not yet. It is quite a lot work to redesign my heap module to work in that way, so I asked before trying it...
Maybe it is complete nonsense...

Comment: Post the code, maybe you made some easy mistakes (f.e. assignments inside functions, (x)range etc.)

Answer (score 2):

We can estimate the cost of allocating the list by comparing the times to build a list:

```
from timeit import Timer

>>> Timer('a = [0]*1000000').timeit(100)
0.587
>>> Timer('for i in xrange(1000000): a[i] = i', 'a = [0] * 1000000').timeit(100)
4.464
>>> Timer('for i in xrange(1000000): a.append(i)', 'a = []').timeit(100)
12.360
```

This suggests that building a million-item list takes about 75 milliseconds longer than pre-allocating it.